# Connectivity to SQL Server on Azure Error: 121 - The semaphore timeout period has expired

Tags: sql-server

I having trouble connecting to a SQL Server database on Azure. We've already added the IP address to the firewall exclusion list and the username/password work when connecting from other machines. We tried with both username/password and MFA.

What else could be causing the problem?

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 121)

Answer (score 2):

try to connect choosing the proper user database here:

[image]

Maybe the user you are using is not able to connect to the master database.

Here is how database firewall rules work:

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure

Comment: Unfortuantely that didn't help. But I'll give you an up-vote anyways because I've seen that work in the past when someone can't login from any machine.

Answer (score 2):

This most likely is related to network or latency where in connection is taking more time than expected.

Try increasing the connection time in SSMS to a larger value (60 seconds, for example):
(This is equivalent to Connection Timeout=60 in the connection string)

[image: Connection Timeout]

**Update**: also, check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978575/azure-sql-server-error-occurred-during-the-pre-login-handshake
Try the disconnect VPN advice

Comment: Connection time-out didn't help, though I've seen others try it with success.

Comment: I hope you're wrong about the VPN because I think this machine is inside the company network and disconnecting isn't an option.

Comment: @JonathanAllen and just to be 100% sure, it is SQL Server on a VM in Azure, not an Azure SQL DB, right ?

Comment: I believe that it is Azure SQL DB, not a VM.

Comment: @JonathanAllen maybe it has run out of sessions ? You know that Azure SQL DB has restrictions on how many sessions / connections it can handle, especially number of sessions running some requests (queries). Scale up Azure SQL DB to increase number of concurrent sessions, that could possibly help